# What is the equivalent of Python's file_object.readline() in the GNU readline module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnu, readline

I've looked through the (Python 3.3) documentation for the GNU-based readline module, and I can see how to do almost everything I want to do except read a line. I can't tell how to use the readline module and ask for the next line as one does with less sophistication in sys.stdin.readline().

So how can I use Python's GNU readline facilities as a souped-up sys.stdin.readline()?

Comment: if `readline` is available then `input()` uses it for interactive input automatically.

Comment: Thank you. GNU readline + raw_input() was what I wanted; I was not trying to execute code but get shell input.

Comment: `input()` in Python 3.3 is `raw_input()` from Python 2 i.e., `input()` doesn't execute code in Python 3.x

Comment: @JonathanHayward: Could you review the `[python-3.x]` tag on this question? If you used `raw_input()` then you are *not* using Python 3.x, and that tag should be removed.